# How to margin 2 table in Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am repeating my tables through the loop, this will create many adjacent tables, and I am looking for everything to separate the tables (margin, padding, clear both), but still no results, I'm using bootstrap.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Add the code in ```code``` blocks  and not as an image to make it easier to replicate

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2):

Add [margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/)

```
<table class="table my-5">...
```

should do the job